# Client Code Generation from WSDL in .NET

Tags: asp.net

I am posting my 1st question here so if i do any mistake then i do apologize. I want to generate a client code form the WSDL files. but i am very new to this so so some body can give me a bit more knowledge then it will be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, typically you would right click a project in Visual Studio, click "Add Service Reference", and give it a URL to the WSDL / Endpoint and bam; there it is. Is there something other than that you were thinking of?

Answer (score 1):

Use the svcutil assuming you are using wcf:

`svcutil /language:[vb or cs] /out:[Name of Proxy.[cs or vb]] /config:[name of config file] [location of metadata]`

Excample with just the wsdl location could be:

`svcutil http://localhost/test.svc?wsdl`

The above will generate a config file for you and client code for you to access to service.